# HTML webpage not displaying picture!

Tags: pi-zero, web-server, server, image

I have a headless Pi Zero that's connected to the internet through the USB ethernet gadget from my computer.

Through SSH (with Powershell), I'm running a Python3 script on the Pi which will start an HTTP server (using Python's native *http.server* and *socketserver* library). The Pi will put a local HTML file `index.html` that's in its SD card online for me to view from my PC by going to `raspberrypi.local:8000`.

The `index.html` file is supposed to contain some text and an image. When I run the server on my Pi and view the `index.html` file through `raspberrypi.local:8000`, I can see the text just fine. However, the image doesn't appear (just a broken image placeholder).

Here is the code for my `index.html` file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pi Cam</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#868167;"></body>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:Calibri" style="text-align:center">Here is a photo of a dog!</h1>
<img src="/focustest.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why I can't view the image. The image is located in the same directory as the index file, but it's not working. Does anyone know what's going on?

My Python code is:

```
import picamera
import logging
from http import server
import _thread
from ctypes import *
import os
import http.server
import socketserver
import time

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
time.sleep(1)
camera.capture('focustest.jpg')
time.sleep(1)
camera.stop_preview()
camera.close()
print('Image captured. Starting server... ')
print('')

#==============================================================================

try:
    PORT = 8000
    class MyHttpRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
            self.path = 'index.html'
            return http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)
    
    Handler = MyHttpRequestHandler
    
    socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
    
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
        print("HTTP Server Serving at Port", PORT)
        httpd.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    httpd.shutdown()
    httpd.socket.close()
    print('Server shut down.')
```

Comment: what do you see when you navigate to `raspberrypi.local:8000/focustest.jpg`

Comment: @JaromandaX Hmm, strangely, I see the index file! (but still without a picture)

Comment: Guessing src="/focustest.jpg" -> src="focustest.jpg" or src="/home/pi/focustest.jpg"

Comment: The Pythin server code is obviously sending index.html for **every** request

Comment: @CoderMike Nope, not working either.

Comment: @JaromandaX I've added my Python code to the question. Would you mind taking a quick look?

Comment: I don't know pythin very well, but I can see it always sends index.html for every request ... `self.path = 'index.html'`